# Change the line color of a line graph based on a data value in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to change the color of a line in my line graph in SSRS based on a data value. I have the code below. If I leave the false part out, the line I want becomes pink, but the other lines are black. If I put the false part in, then all the lines become invisible. Any thoughts? This code is in the expression box in the line fill color property. Thanks.

```
=IIf(Fields!Manufacturer.Value = "PRASCO LABS","Hot Pink","#00000000")
```

Comment: What colour do you want to see when the manufacturer is not `PRASCO LABS`?

Comment: It doesnt matter. Random colors will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to overwrite the specified palette colours for that one Manufacturer, you can use:

```
=IIf(Fields!Manufacturer.Value = "PRASCO LABS", "HotPink", Nothing)
```

By specifying `Nothing`, this just tells the chart to use the normal colour from the palette.

I have the following Chart using the normal horrible standard SSRS palette:

[image]

Note that `PRASCO LABS` is **Red**.

Apply the above expression to the Series Fill property:

[image]

`PRASCO LABS` is now a nice **Hot Pink** as required.

Comment: I put in your expression and it returned with all of the lines black.

Comment: Are you sure you used `HotPink` (i.e. no space) and not `Hot Pink`, which won't work? I had to amend your original expression.

Comment: Yes I copied and pasted how you had it, exactly. All the lines end up black, its weird.

Comment: I tried this expression as well. It gave me the line I want in pink, but all the others are still in black.

Comment: =SWITCH(
 Fields!Manufacturer.Value = "PRASCO LAB", "HotPink",
 Fields!Manufacturer.Value <> "PRASCO LAB", "Nothing"
)

Comment: Also, If I change the color to say, lime green, in the second part of the if statement, it will change the other manufacturers to lime green which is weird. it just wont work random colors. Do I need to change something in my color pallete?

Comment: Your `Switch` expression won't work because `"Nothing"` is in quotes, so SSRS treats it as a literal colour. Remove the quotes to make it work as the SSRS null value as required. `HotPink` and `Lime` are proper colours so work fine.

Comment: Still did not work, the line I want is in pink, but the other ones are still in black. This is really starting to tick me off.